# Use java.util.Optional to return null for subfield of Optional type

Tags: java, option-type

Is it possible to test an `Optional` and return either 1) a subfield (or method) of the instance being tested or 2) null if the instance being tested is null?

Here's an example (doesn't compile):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    A a1 = null;

    LocalDate a_date_field = Optional.ofNullable(a1).orElse(???).date; // <--- I need this line ...
    LocalDate a_date_field = a1 == null? null : a1.date; // <---- ... to work like this line
}

static class A {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
}
```

Yes, you you can supply the `Optional::orElse()` with a new instance:

```
LocalDate a_date_field = Optional.ofNullable(a1).orElse(new A()).date;
```

But this is just incorrect. Since `a` is null, `a_date_field` should be null as well.

Supplying the field with `null` obviously won't work:

```
String afield = Optional.ofNullable(a1).orElse(null).field;
```

This throws NPE.

Is this possible with `Optional`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

```
LocalDate a_date_field = Optional.ofNullable(a1)
                                 .map(a -> a.date)
                                 .orElse(null);
```

Another interesting method would be to say that you want `now()` if `a1` is null, by using the [`orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
LocalDate a_date_field = Optional.ofNullable(a1)
                                 .map(a -> a.date)
                                 .orElseGet(() -> LocalDate.now());
```

Or the shorter form:

```
                                 .orElseGet(LocalDate::now);
```

Note that `orElse` and `orElseGet` applies for both `a1 == null` and `a1.date == null`.